# How to extract characters from an array in column-major order?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to have java read my array and output what is in the array by column.
Here is my code so far where I created the array and pulled a text file into that array:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTryTwo {
    // Written by Nathan Hobson
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String str = "";
        char[][] ar = new char[6][7];
        final int size = 42;
        int count = 0, len;

        File file = new File("/Users/nathanhobson/Desktop/Array.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        str = sc.nextLine();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            str = str + "\n" + sc.nextLine();
        }
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        len=charArray.length;
        for(int a=0; a<6; a++) {
            if(count>size) {
                break;
            }
            for(int b=0; b<7; b++) {
                if(count>size) {
                    break;
                }
                else if(len<size && count>=len) {
                    ar[a][b]='*';
                }
                else {
                    ar[a][b]=charArray[count];
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The 2 dimensional array:");
        for(int a=0; a<6; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<7; b++) {
                System.out.print(ar[a][b]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is how to code java to read the array by column(each column from top to bottom). I know it will just be a few lines of code but I cannot find an example in my book or online so I am asking now in stackoverflow. I hope that this was the right way to ask a question on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are storing the array of characters in a 1D array, `charArray`, then placing those values into a 2D character array, `ar`. I would recommend directly placing the characters into a 2D array like so.

```
char[][] charMatrix = new char[6][7];
Scanner charScanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/nathanhobson/Desktop/Array.txt"));

//temp array for each line
char[] lineArr;

for(int i = 0; i < charMatrix.length; i++) {
    lineArr = charScanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    charMatrix[i] = lineArr;
}
```

In order to print out the columns of an array, you loop through each row index for every column index.

```
for(int col = 0; col < charMatrix[0].length; col++) {
    for(int row = 0; row < charMatrix.length; row++) {
        System.out.println(charMatrix[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

You can print the columns in what ever manner you would like, that's just one method how you would go about accessing the elements by column.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry as a new coder I am not sure where to put in the code you gave me into eclipse? Are you saying I should just delete all my code and replace with what you wrote?

Comment: When ever you are writing a program, it is best to understand what each component is responsible rather than having it just work. As mentioned before, the top chunk of code parses the file and creates the character matrix `charMatrix`. That matrix is then displayed by column in the second chunk. These two chunks can be copied and pasted right next to each other, but it's best to understand exactly what they do and how they do it so you can understand going forward.